# Why is this jQuery code written in functional style doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming

I have this minimal example, and it works fine:

```
var node = $('div');
var fun1 = function(filter) { return node.find(filter) };
console.log(fun1('span'));
```

DOM:

```
<div><span>text</span></div>
```

It seems logical, that as I'm only passing the argument to the next function, I can get rid of it and simply refer to the `find` function:

```
var node = $('div');
var fun2 = node.find;
console.log(fun2('span'));
```

But it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'pushStack'`.

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with this?

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wyVhW/

Comment: fun2 is not a function. it is a variable which holds object.

Comment: Yes, it's a variable which holds an object. And that object is a function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lost the context of `node` when you assigned a reference to the `find` function to `fun2`. You can get that context back by [calling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) `fun2` with it:

```
fun2.call(node, 'span');
```

Or, so you don't have to do that every time, [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the reference to `find` back to `node`:

```
var fun2 = node.find.bind(node);
```

Here's an [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/wyVhW/4/).

Update (thanks [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271767/why-is-this-jquery-code-written-in-functional-style-doesnt-work/18271869#comment26800083_18271869)): If you need to support old browsers that don't implement `Function.prototype.bind` you can either use the polyfill detailed on the MDN article linked to previously, or use [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which does the same thing:

```
var fun2 = $.proxy(node.find, node);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Note that for old-IE compatibility jQuery provides `$.proxy`, which does the same thing as `bind`.

Comment: hmm, okay, the first `node` seems to be redundant then, and looks a bit awkward, I think I will use `$.fn.find.bind(node);`